# Twitter Bootstrap collapse panel sideways

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, panel

So for those who are better with css hopefully they can help me, or steer me in a different direction. I'm trying to flip a bootstrap panel sideways with an accordion collapse. I've gotten this far. But I'm having issues with panel body content.

The real issue is flipping the content back 90 
I'm not sure of a better way to do it

From the picture below you can see the problem

[image]

My jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cr1t/aegrguu1/1/

```
.panel-group
{
    width: 380px;
    z-index: 100;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%) rotate(-90deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: right top;
    -moz-transform: translateX(-100%) rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform-origin: right top;
    -o-transform: translateX(-100%) rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform-origin: right top;
    transform: translateX(-100%) rotate(-90deg);
    transform-origin: right top;
}

.panel-heading
{
    width: 100%;
}

.panel-title
{
    height: 18px;
}

 .panel-title a
    {
        float: right;
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: 10px 310px;
        margin: -10px -310px;
    }

.panel-body
{
    height: 310px;
}

.panel-group span
{
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%) rotate(90deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: right top;
    -moz-transform: translateX(-100%) rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform-origin: right top;
    -o-transform: translateX(-100%) rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform-origin: right top;
    transform: translateX(-100%) rotate(90deg);
    transform-origin: right top;
}

.panel-group .panel span
{
    margin-left: 350px;
    margin-top: 390px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}

.bordered {
    border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a good way to go about this unless this is some kind of responsive site that flips back and forth to different states. And even then its not a great idea. You can make it work if all you are trying to do is fit things back together however since you have flipped everything 90 all of your left right margins become top bottom margins and same with your padding making this an absolute nightmare to maintain and improve on. This is how i got it to work messing with the margins:

```
enter code here
```

http://jsfiddle.net/feonh638/

The best way to do this would be to take out the individual elements and rebuild them vertically. If you go to the bootstrap docs you should find each individual element and how to use them. I cant really tell you where to start as you should really start from scratch. It will save you a lot of time and headaches in the future.

Comment: I agree with you that was probably not the best way.

I did what you suggested and rebuild the panel this is what I came up with.
http://jsfiddle.net/cr1t/aegrguu1/3/

Going to go ahead and mark your answer as correct, Thanks.